# Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4.0 Client Profile

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-client-profile

We are a .NET component vendor, our product needs to connect to the internet to be activated. In Visual Studio 2010, as soon as you create a new WinForms project the .NET Framework 4.0 *Client Profile* is selected not providing the necessary support for internet connections.

Despite this arguable Default chioce, is there something we can do to switch .NET Framework into Visual Studio automatically to .NET Framework 4.0 Full?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that every time the component is used (ie even on the end users machine) your component makes a call to the internet?

Comment: No absolutely, but the app won't compile because some of the necessary references are not included in the .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile for every new project our customers start.

Answer (score 2):

Someone has put together a hack to sort this out. You need to change the Visual Studio templates and rebuild the template cache. This is describe in detail here:

http://blog.rolpdog.com/2010/04/changing-default-framework-profile-in.html

I know I necro'd an old post but I ran into the same problem and it helps to have the proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. JUST DO IT. Seriously.

Open project properties. Switch supported .NET framework to 4.0 full.

The choice is actually not arguable at all - most client applications greatly benefit from it.

Comment: I think what he meant is that the problem is that he has to do it manually for each new project they use... and since they're vendor, so does all of their clients that use their software... and I can see why that can be a problem for some...

Comment: This is, though, not what he asked. So, you tell me hw is not able to formulate a coherent question? I prefer not to make this assumption. Btw., even vendors dont make thoudssands of projects per day. And it is fully documented how to make your own templates.

Comment: Sorry not have been clear enough, btw provinding a project template is not good enough because if somebody forget to use it would incur in this quite frustrating compilation error.

Comment: Still not solvable. At one point, as developer, please take responsibility for your actions. THis is one such thing. For 99% of the client projects, client profile is good enough. The default makes sense.